# Is this the most elegant/safe/recommended solution for this situation?

Tags: c++, c, format

I would like to have the `else`instruction for the first `if`. Something like this:

```
if (vowels_counter >= consonants_counter)
    for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)
        for (j = 0; vowels[j]; j++)
            if (ntca[i] == vowels[j])
            {   ntca[i] += 1;
                break;
            }
else
    for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)...
```

But you see how the `else` is connected to the second `if`:

```
if (vowels_counter >= consonants_counter)
        for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)
            for (j = 0; vowels[j]; j++)
                if (ntca[i] == vowels[j])
                {   ntca[i] += 1;
                    break;
                }

                else
                    for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)...
```

I solved this situation by putting the nested `if`and the `for` in braces like this:

```
   if (vowels_counter >= consonants_counter)
        for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)
            {for (j = 0; vowels[j]; j++)
                {if (ntca[i] == vowels[j])
                   {ntca[i] += 1;
                    break;
                   }
                }
            }

   else
        for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)...
```

Is this the most elegant/safe/recommended solution? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that you want the indentation to affect how the program is interpreted, is that true?

Comment: There is another solution: **always** use braces with `if`, `else`, `for`, `do`, `while`. This way the intention becomes more clear and besides other benefits, the problem you have now doesn't occur. Ever.

Comment: something like that, if it would be possible, Vaughn Cato

Comment: Wishful thinking aside. This kind of control statement nesting should fail sensible code reviews.

Comment: I believe the language you are looking for is Python.

Comment: There is always another solution the better question is what are you trying to do? You can very easily locate vowels in a string using either a bool or better yet a recursive function with a switch case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there another solution for this situation without using braces?

That is the wrong question. The real question is: is there ever a reason to NOT use braces? NO. Just use braces. Your colleagues, and future-you, will thank you later.

Comment: "this is the wrong question" - unless you're entering an obfuscated c competition: http://www.ioccc.org/

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is not so simple: the `else` binds to the closest pending `if` statement.  You need to at least put braces around the body of one of the `for` statements, or worse, add an empty `else;` clause to the nested `if`.

But this is *NOT* what you should do!

Bear in mind that it is considered bad style to not use braces for statements commanded by `if`, `for`, `while`, `do` etc. that are not restricted to a single line. It is **error prone** and not very readable. Use braces generously and keep your code safe from later changes by less savvy (or less sober) programmers that would break it too easily.

Classic Kernighan and Ritchie style looks like this:

```
    if (vowels_counter >= consonants_counter) {
        for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++) {
            for (j = 0; vowels[j]; j++) {
                if (ntca[i] == vowels[j]) {
                    ntca[i] += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use braces around the body of the `if` statement, it's the simplest and most readable option:

```
if (vowels_counter >= consonants_counter)
{
  for (...
}
else
{
  for (...
}
```

but just for fun:

```
if (vowels_counter >= consonants_counter)
  for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; vowels[j] && ntca[i] != vowels[j]; j++)
      ;

    ntca[i] += (vowels[j] && ntca[i] == vowels[j]);
  }
else
  for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++) // ...
```

Answer (score -3):

The obvious way is to add another `else`, followed by an empty statement (i.e. immediately by a `;`)

```
if (vowels_counter >= consonants_counter)
    for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)
        for (j = 0; vowels[j]; j++)
            if (ntca[i] == vowels[j])
            {   ntca[i] += 1;
                break;
            }
            else ;      // note presence of ; here
else
    for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)
```

However, although it answers the question as asked, this is NOT a technique I would ever recommend.   There are so many ways that such hacks could confuse programmers - including yourself in future - that it is simply not worth it.   Code that is easy to misunderstand is easy to get wrong.

Get into the habit of placing the bodies of `if`, `for`, `else`, etc in curly braces, unless you have a VERY specific and convincing (to someone else) justification not to.    Such things are strongly recommended in most style guides for a good reason.    And remember that indentation does not change the meaning of code in any way.

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote this recommendation.  It actually now makes it all the more worse that this user has now been shown a trick to get away with even fewer braces.  Yes, you explain why you should do this... but the explanation of why not is buried under the code that the user isn't going to look beyond, as noted by this answer getting the check mark while other answers providing the same cautions do not get the check mark.

Comment: This solution exacerbates the problem that braces try to protect us from.  This code quickly becomes unreadable (if it's not already) as soon as the indentation is broken, but worse, if that `else ;` line gets removed either by accident or on purpose (because it looks strange or accidental), now the code is broken.  Braces stand to identify *intent* which is crucially important, and this answer provides extended life for the asker to skate by on terrible practices.

Comment: @Skyp89: accepting this answer is encouraging other programmers to use dirty tricks. What is wrong with a few extra braces that will make your code much sturdier, immune to stupid side effects from later changes by not so shrewd programmers.

Comment: People who are looking for dirty tricks tend to find them anyway - and usually without any cautions whatsoever.   Which would you prefer - an example with an explanation about why NOT to do it?   Or simply the approach without cautions?  [I actually see the latter more often on SO.  And marked up.  So being marked down when giving cautions seems arbitrary and capricious].

Comment: @Peter You listed options A & B.  I want option C, which looks like `chqrlie`'s answer.  And every where *I* personally go on Stack Overflow, I try to make this the case.  Just because A is better than B doesn't mean it's good enough or acceptable.  We want answers in the form of C.

Comment: If you want me to spend downvotes on other answers that are recommending bad practices, all you have to do is point me to them.

Comment: It is one thing to falsely claim that bad techniques do not exist.     It is another to acknowledge bad techniques and explain why they should not be used.    I tend to do the latter.    Pretending that bad techniques don't exist does not stop people learning about them.   And, when they learn about them without any explanation of why they shouldn't, they tend to use them.

Comment: The difference is, despite the plain-text cautions against the bad practice, the code snippet at the top encourages the bad practice.  Contrast this with @chqrlie's answer which explains in plain-text what your answer does with the snippet, explain why it's bad, explains the better solution, and then provides a code snippet demonstrating the correct way to do it.

Comment: The most important part of the difference here is that the worst of the worst programmers who peruse Stack Overflow are just looking for a code snippet to copy-pasta into their code base.  *Your* answer means that some day, I'll be maintaining a code base with this snippet in it.  @chqrlie's answer means that some day, I'll be maintaining a *slightly* less terrible code base.

Comment: chqrlie's answer started with a lie - saying no answer is possible.

Comment: @chqrlie's answer is structured in such a way that requires you to read past the first sentence.  Your answer is structured in such a way that no reading is required, just a copy & paste of the code snippet.  We are downvoting your answer to say to any future readers: "This is not the right way to do it.  Don't copy & paste this snippet."

Comment: If you would employ people who are inclined to copy/paste such snippets without understanding them, I'd say you have bigger problems than their ability to find examples.   Suppressing examples won't change that.   Practically, it is easier to find such things in code reviews and eliminate them if reviewers are educated about the bad techniques.

Comment: @Peter: I corrected my answer.  At first I thought braces were required, then I suggested `else;else` in a comment to MikeCat's answer, then you wrote a complete response with the same idea... We all agree it is a bad idea, illustrated only for completeness and definitely not a suggestion.

Comment: @Peter You don't have to employee such bad coders in order to maintain their code bases.

Comment: Maybe not, nhgrif.   But if you're in that situation, you have more chance of eliminating bad technique if you know what to look for.   Teaching only acceptable technique assumes you can somehow eliminate bad techniques.   That is simply not the case.    Incidents of simple human errors in coding that results in bad technique (or even bad habits) vastly outnumber deliberate use of bad technique.

Comment: i think it's disgraceful that a correct answer has been hounded out because people don't like the style. The answer was correct. end of story.

Comment: Indeed, Richard.   There are many CONSTRUCTIVE approaches that could have been taken to address concerns about an answer describing bad technique and discouraging its use. Instead, they decided to take a bullying approach, in the hope of pressuring me to remove an answer I know to be correct.  I generally take constructive comments on board, edit my posts accordingly, and acknowledge the contribution of those who commented.   I am standing my ground on this, because the approach taken has not been constructive.   Frankly, I'm disgusted.

Comment: And I'm downvoted until Repution=0 for a simple question, from which I learned that it's a bad thing to avoid using braces when these are needed, and a lot of beginners like me could have learned this thing without having all these downvotes ... I didn't encouraged a bad technique I asked about it. Misunderstood ....Thank you! and I flaged the question before reaching Rep<15 to be deleted ... but it's still here ... if it's that bad that everybody gives a downvote, why it's not erased?

Comment: there are here solutions that indeed work but we all understood that there are solutions to  be avoided, there is no reason to use them, that these solutions make the program vulnerable, and if people who saw them would just use them in their programs just because they don't want to do a good job, it's their problem ... this bad habit will turn sometime against them ... you all acted like if a bad solution was posted here, everybody would start to use it ... i guessed that you have the capacity to analyze some answers and to implement in your code what is good ... weak people

Answer (score -4):

One solution is to negate the condition of inner `if` and put the process to `else` closure.

```
if (vowels_counter >= consonants_counter)
    for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)
        for (j = 0; vowels[j]; j++)
            if (!(ntca[i] == vowels[j])); else
            {   ntca[i] += 1;
                break;
            }
else
    for (i = 0; ntca[i]; i++)...
```

Comment: It works, but it's not exactly what one would call elegant, or readable/maintainable.

Comment: better solution, @Joachim Pileborg ?

Comment: I can think of a similar one using `else;else`